# SEO: Using media queries to hide links

Tags: seo, hyperlink, hidden-text, media-queries

I've heard lots of discussion around Google and hidden text. My problem is similar but involves links.

My website's footer is pushed for space at mobile screen size. I could really do with using `display:none` on about 3 of my footer links to save some space.

How would Google react to this from an SEO perspective?

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem. Mediaqueries are made for these types of situations. As long as you dont use weird stuff (`@media screen and min-width: 1px){ a{display:none;}`), you have ntohing to worry about.

Simply rule of thumb: The user should see the exact same thing as bots. If a bot would mimic mobile view, is the content the same as for the user? Yes it is, no problem*.

**With offcourse the standard tricks disregarded*